# The proof of Tomas's restriction theorem $\|\hat{f}(\theta)\|_2\lesssim \|f\|_p$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of Tomas's theorem:

[image]

The proof reads

[image]

My question:

How do we get the estimates

$$\|T_k\ast f \|_{\infty}\lesssim 2^{-(n-1)k/2}\|f\|_{1},\qquad\qquad (1)$$
$$\|T_k\ast f \|_{2}\lesssim 2^{k}\|f\|_{2}.\qquad\qquad (2)$$

We can prove (1) by showing that

$$\|T_k \|_{\infty}\lesssim 2^{-(n-1)k/2}.\qquad \qquad (3)$$

And we can get (2) by proving that

$$\|T_k \|_{1}\lesssim 2^{k}\qquad\qquad (4).$$

I am stuck with (3) and (4).

By definition of $\widehat{d\theta}$ and $K$, we have that, for large enough $k$,

$$T_k (x)=\int_{2^{k-1}\leq |x|\leq 2^k} \left(K\left(\frac{|x|}{2^k}\right)-K\left(\frac{|x|}{2^{k-1}}\right) \right)\int_{\mathbb{S^{n-1}}}e^{\dot{\imath}x\cdot \theta}d\theta.$$

I am not sure of the latter claim of mine. We have
$$k(\frac{x}{2^k})=g(\frac{|x|}{2^k})$$ where $g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. So, given, $\epsilon>0$, we can find $k_{\epsilon}>1$ such that $\int_{2^{k_{\epsilon}}}^{\infty} |g(r)|dr<\epsilon$.
We also have
When $|x|\leq 1$ (say 1 instead of 100 in the proof) we have $K(x)=1$.
So, for every $k\geq 1$, we have
$$D(x):=k(\frac{x}{2^k})-k(\frac{x}{2^{k-1}})=0$$ when $|x|\leq 2^{k-1}$.
That is $D$ is suppoerted in $|x|>2^{k-1}$. But, for large enough $k$, we can overlook $\int_{|x|>2^{k}}D$ because $D$ is a Schwartz function.

A second question:

The proof implicitly uses the fact that

$$\sum_{k\geq 1} \|T_k\ast f\|_{p^{\prime}}\lesssim \|f\|_{p^{\prime}}$$.

I would appreciate a hint for this too.

Comment: I agree that the original paper is not understandable because the main estimates you ask for are not explained. Actually they follow since the Fourier transform of the surface measure can be expressed through a Bessel function...but one needs some computation. The booklet by Stein: Bejing lectures on Harmonic analysis has full proofs in the chapter on oscillatory integrals but in a more general setting. A detailed proof of  Tomas's result can be found in an expository paper by D. Kriventsov (available online) "The restriction problem and the Tomas Stein theorem".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good references. I will try to understand these estimates then post their proof here hopefully.